# Pulling Image from website based off link

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I currently have the code in place to pull all the image tags in an html document by using the BeautifulSoup library. I was wondering if there was a way in Python to programatically download the image locally to your computer by image pointed to by the link element in the image tags. Here is my code to get all the image tags in a webpage.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Retrieve object containing website information
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
#Pull image tags
print soup.findAll('img')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is, parse the img tag to find the url and download it using something like urllib.urlretrieve.

Comment: urlretrieve is what I was looking for. Thanks.